# Tkinter - Making a button draw an object

Tags: python, button, canvas, tkinter

How would I bind a button to a function that draws a red square using tkinter? It's just a course in high school so I really don't know what I'm doing.

This is the square:

```
def __init__(self,master):
    self.myCanvas=Canvas(master,width=300,height=200)
    self.myCanvas.pack()

    self.box=self.myCanvas.create_rectangle(50,50,70,100,fill="red")
```

Comment: Do you want to interactively draw it by clicking and dragging the mouse, or have a square just appear at a random spot when you click a button?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `command` argument.

```
from Tkinter import *

class WindowWithButtonAndCanvas:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.myCanvas=Canvas(master,width=300,height=200)
        self.myCanvas.pack()

        self.myButton = Button(text="click me!", command=self.button_clicked)
        self.myButton.pack()

    def button_clicked(self):
        self.box=self.myCanvas.create_rectangle(50,50,70,100,fill="red")

root = Tk()
x = WindowWithButtonAndCanvas(root)
root.mainloop()
```